# Visual Studio 2019/C++ bug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2019

I'm using native C++ with Visual Studio 2019 16.11.8.
I don't understand this: whis can the *false* keyword be used as NULL (or nullptr)? Below the test code:

```
bool test(bool* pb)
{
    if (NULL != pb)
        return *pb;
    else
        return false;
}

void main()
{
    test(false); // compiles (not what I was expecting)
    test(true); // won't compile: error C2664: 'test' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'bool' to 'bool *'
}
```

I have tried online compilers tool, and they do not accept the

```
test(false);
```

line, which sounds to me what the normal behavior should be.

In addition, this behavior can cause issues with overloaded methods. i.e., you have a test(bool* pb) method and an overloaded version with a pointer: test(int* pv)

```
bool test(bool* pb)
{
    if (NULL != pb)
        return *pb;
    else
        return false;
}

bool test(int* pb)
{
    if (NULL != pb)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void main()
{
    test(false); // won't compile anymore: error C2668: 'test' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
    test(true); // won't compile: error C2664: 'test' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'bool' to 'bool *'
}
```

BTW I'm also using VS2012, which has the same behavior with the same test codes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MSVC treats the expression `false` as a *null pointer constant*.

A null pointer constant can be implicitly converted to any pointer type, resulting in a null pointer value.

The correct behavior according to the standard is to treat only integer literals with value `0` as null pointer constants. Although it has value `0`, `false` is not an integer literal.

However this rule is only in place since resolution of [CWG issue 903](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#903). Before that every integral constant expression with value `0` was a null pointer constant.

MSVC is not implementing the defect report with default flags and still follows this old rule, according to which the expression `false` is a null pointer constant.

If you give MSVC the flag `/permissive-` to make it behave more standard-conform and implement the new rule. With `/std:c++20` or higher this is also set by default, if I am not mistaken.

Note however, that you still have this problem if you use a literal `0` in your code and yes, it can affect overload resolution.

Values other than `0`, even if an integer literal, are never null pointer constants and therefore cannot be converted to pointers implicitly. This also applies to `true` which has value `1`. Therefore overload resolution may be affected by the specific value passed as argument.

Null pointer constants are what makes `NULL` work to initialize and compare null pointers, by having `NULL` expand either to an integer literal with value `0` or to `nullptr`. The latter is, since C++11, an alternative null pointer constant.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried the 2 options you mention, and I get warnings:
2>cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/permissive-'
2>cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/std:c++20'
I don't know what I have missed (BTW I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.8)

Comment: @ggo Have a look at the documentation. At the bottom it explains how to set the option from Visual Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-170

Comment: thank you, the problem was that the project is in "Visual Studio 2012 mode". With a new project, the options are accepted. However, false is still implicitely converted to nullptr. But it's ok, I can live with this. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is not bug.
test function has like parameter pointer. false == 0 == NULL. You can have a NULL pointer.
But true = 1. You cann not transform 1 (bool or int) to pointer.

Change it to:

```
bool test(int& pb)
{
    if (pb)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

An `pb != NULL` or `pb != false` is OK, but better is `if(pb)`

Comment: It is a "bug" (intentionally though). See user17732522's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your intention is to test a boolean value and an integer value by passing *pointers* to these values to test functions.  However, when you call the test functions (`pb` and `pv`) you are inadvertently not providing *pointers* to these values.

```
test(false); // error C2668: 'test' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
test(true); // error C2664: 'test' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'bool' to 'bool *'
```

In C and C++ type promotion will allow `false` to be treated as NULL (nullptr) because `false` is valued as 0.  This will not be allowed for `true` because true is valued as 1.

The first error is due to the compiler not being able to decide which `test()` you want to call (because you are passing nullptr (a so called *null pointer constant type*) in both cases.

The second error is due to the compiler not *allowing* you to convert the parameter to a *pointer.*

Comment: Actually I was not inadvertently not providing pointers. I am intentionally not providing pointers in the test code, because I wanted to confirm this behavior (that I was not expecting): false is implicitely converted to NULL (or nullptr). Actually, the first "problem" I encountered was the 2nd problem.

Comment: Well, you are right, the 2nd test was probably not a so interesting test. I agree that it's "normal" to have the 2nd error (cannot convert parameter 1 from 'bool' to 'bool *'). The main "issue", according to me, is that false is implicitely converted to NULL, even with the /permissive- option. Thank you.